# ShowModal window opens NSOpenPanel will be auto closed in Delphi FMX

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey, nsopenpanel

I'm using the code http://jed-software.com/blog/?p=538 to allow user to select a folder under MAC OSX. It works fine if I place a button in the main form and click this button to open NSOpenPanel.

However, if I open a modal window with ShowModal, then, place a button in this modal window, click this button to open NSOpenPanel, after selected the folder in NSOpenPanel, no matter I click the OK or Cancel button, both NSOpenPanel and this modal window will be closed automatically.

I appreciate for any help to fix this problem.

Comment: What Delphi version do you use?

Comment: @Erik : Have you seen my answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `ModalResult` of a Button is not equal to `mrNone` and

If a form with ShowModal is opened,

```
 Form2.ShowModal;
```

`Button1 on Form2`

[image]

after the program code is executed in the event `Button1Click(...)` .

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   OpenDialog1.Execute;
end;
```

When the `OpenDialog1` is closed, `Form2` is terminated immediately.
It does not matter whether to end `OpenDialog1` with `ok` or `cancel`.